# Breaking Down Combined Column Values into Different Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a pharmacy table that has PharmacyID and Regimen as below;

```
PharmacyID  Regimen 
140646      3TC/D4T/EFV
140653      ABC/D4T/NVP
```

My desire is to get something like this;

```
PharmacyID  Regimen 
140646      3TC
140646      D4T
140646      EFV
140653      ABC
140653      D4T
140653      NVP
```

Am stuck in googling i have not tried any solution

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Postgresql? The answer wont be the same...

Comment: I am using MS SQL

Comment: Using a string split function (as in the accepted answer) is not a bad idea, but there are much better approaches [here: Aaron Bertrand about String Splitters](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: have to correct myself: ... *as in the previously accepted answer* Thx :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work with an *on-the-fly* string split approach via XML:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(PharmacyID INT,Regimen VARCHAR(100)); 
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(140646,'3TC/D4T/EFV')
                      ,(140653,'ABC/D4T/NVP');

WITH Casted AS (
                SELECT PharmacyID
                      ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT Regimen AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS TheXML
                FROM @tbl
               )
SELECT PharmacyID 
      ,a.x.value(N'(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Regimen
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY Casted.TheXML.nodes(N'/x') AS A(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create function [dbo].[udf_splitstring] (@tokens    varchar(max),
                                   @delimiter varchar(5))
returns @split table (
  token varchar(200) not null )
as



  begin

      declare @list xml

      select @list = cast('<a>'
                          + replace(@tokens, @delimiter, '</a><a>')
                          + '</a>' as xml)

      insert into @split
                  (token)
      select ltrim(t.value('.', 'varchar(200)')) as data
      from   @list.nodes('/a') as x(t)

      return

  end  



    CREATE TABLE #Table111
        ([PharmacyID] int, [Regimen] varchar(11))
    ;

    INSERT INTO #Table111
        ([PharmacyID], [Regimen])
    VALUES
        (140646, '3TC/D4T/EFV'),
        (140653, 'ABC/D4T/NVP')
    ;
    select [PharmacyID], token FROM #Table111 as t1
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].UDF_SPLITSTRING([Regimen],'/') as t2
```

output

```
PharmacyID  token
140646  3TC
140646  D4T
140646  EFV
140653  ABC
140653  D4T
140653  NVP
```

Comment: Is ths for MySQL, MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: Your string-splitter-function is far away from optimal: 1) *multi-statement* TVF (**very bad performance!!**)  and 2) not save with special characters (try a `@tokens` with a `&` sign...

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp1(string1 varchar(max))
Insert into #temp1 
Values('3TC/D4T/EFV'),('ABC/D4T/NVP')

    SELECT 
   Replace(Replace(CAST( Tbl.Col.query('.') as varchar(max)),'<a>',''),'</a>','')
    FROM 
(Select cast('<a>'+ replace(string1, '/', '</a><a>') + '</a>' as xml)as t 
  from #temp1) tl
Cross apply 
    tl.t.nodes('/a') AS Tbl(Col)
```

Comment: This answer is not safe with forbidden characters. Try to place `&` in your input string (something like `'3TC/D&T/EFV'`). The rest is identical with my answer (well, a *sub-select* instead to a `CTE`) :-D

Comment: And (just saw this): You are using `.query()` completely wrong! You cast its result and remove the tags on string level! Try to change this to `.value()` as in my answer...